# Как перевести int в String?

Tags: java

Например,

```
int a = 6;
String b = (String)a; //не работает
```

Нужно получит

```
b = "6"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int a = 6;
String b = String.valueOf(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

1-вый способ простой

```
int a = 4;
String b = a + "";
```

2-ой способ

```
int e =6;
String tt = String.valueOf(e);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] // то, что вы назвали вторым способом, кстати, уже присутствует в предыдущем ответе.